# I need you both the same - is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning

Is it correct to say 'I need you both the same'?
I want to say 'I need you both equally' but need it for the song with the word 'same'. 
Doesn't it mean 'I need you both to be the same'?
Do you have any idea of what I can say instead?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This question is more of an opinion, since you are writing a song and, as we know, that does not require immaculate grammar!

With a bit of context, the listener will understand your meaning, I believe.

You are meaning it to imply the word "amount".

> I need you both the same [amount]

I don't think there is a better way of saying this whilst still ending with the word same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *entirely* correct, but you can get away with a lot in song.  As a lyric, it's fine. It implies that you need both people the same *amount*, as in, you are *equally in love* with both of them.

A crude example:

> I need you both the same
>   Why do we have to play the game
>   Why make me have to choose
>   Knowing one of us will lose
>   Two loves is not too much.

Meanwhile "I need you both to be the same" implies that you want the two people to become *more similar* to each other.  This is probably not what you want to say.